# printf not printing integer stored in variable

Tags: c, printf, scanf

For some weird reason when I input the values in the marks section, the printed values are all 0, please help, I tried running a smaller version of the code and it worked I don't know why this doesn't.
here is the code:
Stack overflow keeps giving me an error since apparently most of my question is code so pls ignore this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int marksComm;
    char gradeComm[1];
    int marksEco;
    char gradeEco[1];
    int marksCompsys;
    char gradeCompsys[1];
    int marksProg;
    char gradeProg[1];
    int marksDis;
    char gradeDis[1];
    int marksLab;
    char gradeLab[1];
    int marksPhy;
    char gradePhy[1];
    printf("CCS001\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksComm);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradeComm);

    printf("\nCCS009\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksEco);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradeEco);

    printf("\nCSC111\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksCompsys);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradeCompsys);

    printf("\nCSC112\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksProg);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradeProg);

    printf("\nCSC113\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksDis);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradeDis);

    printf("\nCSC126\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksPhy);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradePhy);

    printf("\nCSC115\nMarks> ");
    scanf("%d", &marksLab);
    printf("Grade> ");
    scanf("%s", &gradeLab);

    printf("\nCourse Code       Marks      Grade\n");
    printf("CCS001             %d         %s \n", marksComm, gradeComm);
    printf("CCS009             %d         %s \n", marksEco, gradeEco);
    printf("CSC111             %d         %s \n", marksCompsys, gradeCompsys);
    printf("CSC112             %d         %s \n", marksProg, gradeProg);
    printf("CSC113             %d         %s \n", marksDis, gradeDis);
    printf("CSC115             %d         %s \n", marksLab, gradeLab);
    printf("CSC126             %d         %s \n", marksPhy, gradePhy);
}
```

Comment: Your string buffers are far too small.

Comment: `char gradeComm[1];` maybe you want to use `char gradeComm;`  and update your scanf instead of the 1 character array with no space for a null terminator. Or do you expect a string of characters as input?

Comment: All the `[1]` arrays are not big enough. You need room for the input string and the terminating null character. `[1]` only has room for the null, not the input.

Comment: If you change from `char XXX[1]` to `char XXX`, change the `scanf()` format to `" %c"` -- don't forget the space before it.

Comment: What does your input look like? Are "marks" percentages, and "grades" letter grades? Can the letter grades include a "+" or "-"? This kind of info is neded for us to help you.

Comment: @Barmar @drescherjm thank you so much increasing the size of the arrays worked
might i ask why it works since I don't get how changing `char` fixes `int` since I kind of have an idea of what was wrong I expected `char` to be the one that didn't print (sorry if my explanation is bad I just enrolled in uni for comp sci so I don't  understand most stuff)

Comment: " I don't get how changing char fixes int." Welcome to C, where the tiniest mistake results in strange behavior.

Comment: You were trying to fit 2 bytes into a 1-byte array. That doesn't work and causes problems. C doesn't detect errors like this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are two small. C strings are NUL-terminated, so you need a `char` for the letter, and a char for the `NUL`. That's two `char`. But you reserve space for one.

Comment: ok so I increased the size of the array and it worked, tysm I just enrolled to uni doing comp sci so I don't understand most of these stuff. could you mind clarifying why changing `char` fixes the problem with the `int`? Since now that I kind of have an idea of what is wrong I think the `char` is the one that should have had a problem and not the `int` (sorry if what I'm asking doesn't make sense I'm bad at explaining things)

Comment: The bug caused undefined behaviour. Anything can happen when you do that. What probably happened is that you were overwriting memory which happened to be used to store the marks.